Issue with Bounding Boxes When Rendering GeoJSON from Overpass Turbo in React

I’m using Overpass Turbo to get coordinates for US cities, specifically focusing on the state of Arizona. The query I am using is as follows:
[out:json][timeout:180];
area["name"="Arizona"]->.searchArea;
(
  relation(area.searchArea)["admin_level"="6"]["boundary"="administrative"];
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;

I export the data in GeoJSON format and store it locally for rendering in my ReactJS application using the react-simple-maps library. However, when I render the map, it displays three unexpected bounding boxes along with the map data. These bounding boxes are not visible in Overpass Turbo but appear when rendering in the app.
What I’ve Tried:

Querying in Overpass Turbo: I confirmed the query works as intended
in Overpass Turbo, where no bounding boxes are displayed.

Exporting GeoJSON: I export the data and save it locally in GeoJSON
format for rendering. React Code: Here’s how I’m rendering the map
in React
import {
ComposableMap,
Geographies,
Geography,
ZoomableGroup,
} from "react-simple-maps";

const geoUrl = "/geojson/arizona.json"; 

const OhioCityMap = () => {
return (
<div className="flex w-full h-full items-center justify-center overflow-hidden relative">
  <ComposableMap projection="geoAlbersUsa" className="w-full h-full">
    <ZoomableGroup>
      <Geographies geography={geoUrl}>
        {({ geographies }) =>
          geographies
            .filter(
              (geo) =>
                geo.geometry.type === "Polygon" ||
                geo.geometry.type === "MultiPolygon"
            )
            .map((geo) => (
              <Geography
                key={geo.rsmKey}
                geography={geo}
                fill="transparent"
                stroke="blue" 
                strokeWidth={1}
              />
            ))
        }
      </Geographies>
    </ZoomableGroup>
  </ComposableMap>
</div>
  );
};

export default OhioCityMap;



